# Find the nth character from an array of words in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-concatenation

I'd like to create a function (nthChar) that takes 1 parameter - an array of n words.

The function should concatenate the nth letter from each word to construct a new word which should be returned as a string.

The nth letter should be the 1st from the first word in the array, the second from the second word in the array, the third from the third and so on. So:
    nthChar(['I','am','Tom']) should return 'Imm'

Here's my attempt:
    function nthChar(words){

```
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
return words[i].charAt(words.indexOf(words[i]))
}
}
```

Which only seems to grab the first letter of the first word. How would I proceed to the other words of the array before concatenation?

Comment: Hint: Your function is not concatenating anything before returning.

Comment: `return` statement terminates the execution of the function. You should use the `return` keyword after the loop.

Comment: each letter would be `words[i].charAt(i)` , or `words[i][i]` no?

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your code, you can do this

```
function nthChar(arr) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        str = str + words[i][i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

`str` - used to build up the result string

`words[i]` selects the i'th word ... the second [i] in that statement selects the i'th letter in that word

for example: `"Hello World"[6]` is `W`

Bonus: works in IE8 and earlier ...

---

and, just for the hell of it, `void`'s answer in ES6

```
var nthChar = arr => arr.map((i, v) => i[v]).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nthChar(arr){

  return arr.map(function(i, v){
      return i[v];
  }).join("");

}

console.log(nthChar(['I','am','Tom']));
```

So it is returning an array of the characters you want and then it is joining it. Makes sense?

The issue with your code was that you were not concatenating anything to the output. You can access the characters of a `string` as if it is an `array`.

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fxL4645r/1/)

Your code can be:

```
function nthChar(words){
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
       str += words[i].charAt(i);
    }
    return str;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fxL4645r/5/)

Comment: The point of posting an answer shouldn't be just providing a solution. You should explain why his current code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: _"Makes sense?"_ Not really - you've changed the OPs `for` loop for the entirely different `map` - some explanation would be good.

Comment: **your code can be** `str += words[i].charAt(words.indexOf(words[i]))` ... what? no it can't ... that whole indexOf rubbish is stupidity ... his code can be `str += words[i][i];`

Comment: `words.indexOf(words[i])` is just the same as `i` - that is until you get a duplicated word in the array and then the former gives the wrong index

Comment: Yes, there is no need to use the `indexOf` method. Completely redundant.

Comment: Agree.. Couldn't notice it. My Bad. Updated.

Comment: @JaromandaX you don't know anything :P :D? Can you tell me why? With a way to make it work in IE6,7,8?

Comment: @void - I know enough ... `Array.prototype.map` does not exist pre IE9 - seriously, it was a throw away comment (which I threw away)

Comment: @JaromandaX and the second method to achieve the same? Now tell me if the OP need to use it in all the browser from Netscape navigator to Chrome 36/38 whatever can't he use the later method, and if he has a usecase for modern browsers only he can use the prior one.

Comment: @JaromandaX and where did OP mention that he wants to use it in IE8? You assumed it?

Comment: @void - chill out, you're stressing over nothing - where did the OP mention he DIDN'T want to use it in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function nthChar(words){
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0, ln = words.length; i<ln; i++) 
    result += words[i].charAt(i);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: that returns the last character in each word, not what the question asked

Comment: **So: nthChar(['I','am','Tom']) should return 'Imm'** - but he's asking exatly that

Comment: Your function generates the expected output by accident. Please reread the question. "The nth letter should be the 1st from the first word in the array, the second from the second word in the array, the third from the third and so on."

Comment: oh , you're right, i'm really sorry.  Just updated now

Answer (score 0):

This can be as simple as

```
function nthChar(words){
    var s = "";
    for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
      s+= words[i].charAt(i);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/11yc79jn/

This is closest to your original solution, and just uses the loop control variable `i` which is incrementing already as you loop through the `words` array. Of course, also return after the entire loop has run as well.

Comment: Why not use `i` instead of `x`, `s+= words[i].charAt(i);`

Comment: @Tushar no reason, except it's early and I'm clearly not awake enough yet to be answering questions :)